# jar not running without dependable files

Tags: java

I am trying to run an executable jar and my application has conf folder .. the jar is failed to run with below error.. 
How can I run the jar independently?

I want my jar to run independently and I have a conf folder in my application which can be modified in future so want my jar to run in cmd. But when I am running the jar I am getting these errors .
Also, when I put the conf file in the same folder in which jar is there then the jar is running fine but I don't want that to happen. I just want to run the jar since I want to use it as window service..

> log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file
>   [./conf/log4j.properties]. java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   .\conf\log4j.properties (The system cannot find the path specified) at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:372)
>   at
>   org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:403)
>   at dicom_ibe.DicomOrchestrator.(DicomOrchestrator.java:53) at
>   dicom_ibe.DicomManager.main(DicomManager.java:9) log4j:ERROR Ignoring
>   configuration file [./conf/log4j.properties]

Comment: Copy and paste the stack trace as text. Please do not post images.

Comment: Edit the question instead of posting them as comments. It is very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Maybe you are executing the jar with a user without read permission on the conf folder?

Comment: Jar is independent Archive, so it should always run independently.

Comment: jar is running independently but when kept in same folder with conf. If I am running from any other location then its giving ERROR Could not read configuration file [./conf/log4j.properties].